# Como ler informações de ícones de um XML

Tags: php, xml

Estou tentando extrair algumas informações de uma `xml` e não estou conseguindo,  o que consigo obter é a data que está no nó `weather`, mas `icon` e `text` que estão na sequência não estou conseguindo.
As informações anteriores estão em uma estrutura que se repetia até então, nesse caso a mesma é alterada.
O código que tentei recuperar as informações que preciso é esse:

```
foreach($itemIcone->data->item->weather->item as $reg) {  
    // ZERANDO O ARRAY
    $data = array();

        // ÍCONES  
        $data['api']['data']['item']['weather']['item'][] = array 
        (
            // LENDO OS NÓS
            'date' => (string)$reg['date']          
        );

        // ATRIBUINDO AS VARIÁVEIS     
        $Data = $data['api']['data']['item']['weather']['item'][0]['date']; 
        $IcoManha = $data['api']['data']['item']['weather']['item'][0]['date']['icon'][0]['morning'];   
}
```

A imagem do que tenho no momento segue abaixo.

[image: XML]

Comment: Você está utilizando `simplexml` or `domdocument`? Edita sua questão e põe o exemplo do `xml`

Comment: Olá @MarcelodeAndrade, estou usando o simplexml_load_string.